# Gutenberg – How to prevent block from being deleted and reordered/moved

Tags: block-editor

I have a post type which is prepopulated with a Gutenberg block:

```
function blog_block_template() {
  $post_type_event = get_post_type_object( 'event' );
  $post_type_event->template = array(
    array( 'acf/single-event-meta' ),
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'blog_block_template' );
```

This certain block should not be deleted or reordered. I don’t want to use a meta box because the meta box would be rendered below all Gutenberg blocks or on the side which would be confusing for the user.

There’s the `supports` parameter when registering a Gutenberg block which allows to restrict some functionality but I couldn’t find anything about deleting or reordering.

```
'supports' => array( 
    'align'           => false, 
    'customClassName' => false,
    'html'            => false,
    'inserter'        => false,
    'multiple'        => false,
    'reusable'        => false,
),
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some more context would be helpful in identifying a solution, what's the problem that this solves for you?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I added some context. I hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a block template.

For any given post type, you can set up a block template which adds blocks to the Editor whenever you create a new post of that type. These templates have an option called `template_lock` which you can set to `all` which means that users cannot add, move, or delete any blocks.

Of course you probably want to let people add other blocks - but you can still use a template. You would need to create your own wrapper block, one that holds your event block inside of it - and that also allows `InnerBlocks`. This way, your wrapper with its event will always be required, but people can still add, edit, move, and delete any other blocks on the page as needed.